# Where does CPanel stores cron job result files?

Tags: server, cron, cpanel

When a cron job runs, I get an email that says

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK 
Length: 19 [text/html]
Saving to: “filefeed.16” 
0K 100% 4.93M=0s 
2017-03-23 10:10:04 (4.93 MB/s) - “filefeed.16” saved [19/19]
```

So it's my understanding that `Saving to: “filefeed.16”` means that is storing this file somewhere in my server, where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a few hours, I found it was quite simple, depending on the user who is running the cron job, it will store this file in the user's directory, for example, let's say I am using `user_03`, it will save it on `/home/user_03/`.